# Website Images to Big or Small for the Displayed Size

Tags: html, css, image, image-processing, optimization

Hi anyone bothered to read this,

Recently decided I wanted to optimise the websites at work and also increase the quality of the content.

In the past any staff member was able to post photos so sometimes the photos are far to big or small for the size that they are displayed on the website. These sites are now massive pages and content wise - with over 5000 pages for each of the 7 of them. I wanted to know if there is a way to crawl the site and find images that are too small or too big for the size that they are displayed on the site?

Probably wishful thinking

Comment: Do you have root or shell access to server? If you have you can find all image files easily and find their sizes via a script.

Comment: I do have FTP and Shell access. And I can find all the images easy and the size but the issue is I don't know what size they are displayed at from the images on the server - need to compare the actual size to the size they are displayed. If they are too small i need to replace - if they are too large I need to resize and replace the large file on the server

Comment: css tag inappropriate perhaps?

Comment: Images are resized in css from there original size - so not sure I agree